# $\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{3}x)}{x}$ as x approaches zero

Tags: calculus, limits

I know it's not direct substitution cause i end up with zero. kindly, explain it too please thank you

Comment: is that the limit or is it $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)}{x}$

Comment: Write it as ${1\over 3}\cdot{\sin(x/3)\over x/3}$ and use a well-known limit.

Answer (score 2):

Use [L'hospital rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule):
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\sin(x/3)}{x}= \lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{\cos(x/3)}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$$

Comment: its $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{3x}\right)}{x}$

Answer (score 2):

Starting from $\sin(x/3)/x$, you can make the substitution $ x=3X$  obtaining $\sin(X)/(3X)=1/3 \sin(X)/X$. Since $\sin(X)/X$ is known to approach $1$ when $X$ tends to zero, you get that the limit is $1/3$.

A demonstration of the well known limit of $\sin(x)/x$ when $x$ approaches zero is given by $$\sin(x)\leq x\leq\tan(x)$$

$$1/\sin(x)\geq1/x\geq1/\tan(x)$$

and multiplying by $\sin(x)$

$$1\geq\sin(x)/x\geq\cos(x)$$

which implies that the limit is $1$.

Comment: The good way to do it.

Comment: @GitGud How do you prove that $sin(x)/x$ goes to $1$ as $x$ goes to $0$?

Comment: You can either use geometrical arguments which lead to a simple double inequality which you solve via squeeze/sandwich theorem, or else you most simply apply Bernoulli-de l'Hôpital rule

Comment: @Surb Not with L'hôpital. That limit is required to prove that $\sin '=\cos$. Plus I'm almost sure that this limit is already known by the OP.

Comment: Hi, I edited my answer with a short proof of the famous limit of $\sin(x)/x$

Answer (score 1):

Using the *classic* limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ and the substitution $y=\frac x3$ we have

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac x3\right)}{x}=\frac13\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac x3\right)}{\frac x3}=\frac13\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin(y)}{y}=\frac13$$

Answer (score 0):

In a neighbourhood you can expand into a Taylor series
$$
\frac{f(0) + f'(0) x + O(x^2)}{x}
= f'(0) + O(x) 
\to f'(0) = \frac{1}{3} \cos(0) = \frac{1}{3}
$$

for $x\to 0$.

Answer (score -3):

Whenever $x\neq0$,

$$
\sin\left(\frac{\frac{1}{3}x}{x}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)
$$

So it approaches $\sin\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$

Comment: read the question again, you have the wrong function.

Comment: @VishwaIyer The question was edited after I posted my answer.